# Change type of telephone field in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

I want to change the input for the telephone field in the checkout from **text** to **number**.

I looked into it 2 years ago and created [this topic](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Change-telephone-input-field-to-number/td-p/93660) on the Magento community forum. There were some answers there, but none worked. Now, two years later, another of our customers has asked for this, but I still can't seem to find a fix. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: is it solved or not?

Comment: It is but i can't select my own answer till the problem is 2 days old ^^'

Comment: ok so can you share me URL?

Comment: in which for you want to set that number format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the best way to change the input type is to add a different template to the LayoutProcessor and change the input type in there.

```php
// Vendor/Module/Plugin/Magento/Checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

protected function updateElementTmpls(&$jsLayoutResult)
{
    $shippingAddress = &$jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'];
    $billingAddress = &$jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['billing-address']['children']['form-fields']['children'];

    $inputPathPhone = 'YourCompany_YourModule/ui/form/element/phone-overwrite';
        

    $shippingAddress['telephone']['config']['elementTmpl'] = $inputPathPhone;
    $billingAddress['telephone']['config']['elementTmpl'] = $inputPathPhone;

}
```

```html
<!-- vendor/module/view/base/web/template/ui/form/element/phone-overwrite.html -->

<input class="input-text" type="number" data-bind="
    value: value,
    valueUpdate: 'keyup',
    hasFocus: focused,
    css: {focused: value() != '' && value() != ' '},
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled
    }
"/>
```

I don't have the complete code because my LayoutProcessor is editted a lot because we used this for our checkout extension: https://www.bigbridge.nl/magento-2-enhanced-checkout/ (input types will be in the next version).

Update: At the end I found out that the 'tel' format is nicer for phone numbers so I would recommend replacing number with tel ;)

Comment: Great Job mate.

Comment: @sanne It would have been nice if you had started the code fragments with the filenames, like `// app/code/Vendor/Module/path/to/the/file.php` or something like that

Answer (score 3):

You can try this module

```xml
<!-- app/code/Sanne/Js/etc/module.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sanne_Js" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence> <module name="Magento_Checkout" /></sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

```php
// app/code/Sanne/Js/registration.php

<?php
    
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sanne_Js',
    __DIR__
);
```

```xml
<!-- app/code/Sanne/Js/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0"?>
    
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="phonejs" template="Sanne_Js::js.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

```php
<!-- app/code/Sanne/Js/view/frontend/templates/js.phtml -->

<?php ?>
    
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Elgentos_AddTelephoneInputType/js/phonevalidation":
            {
                "phoneinput":"input[name=telephone]"
            }
    }
}
</script>
```

```js
// app/code/Sanne/Js/view/frontend/web/js/phonevalidation.js

define([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui"
], function($) {
    "use strict";
    
    //creating jquery widget checking phone numbers to remove character, allowed only numbers
    $.widget('phonevalidation.js', {
        _create: function() {
            var widget = this;
            var templateoptions = widget.options;
            $('body').on('input', templateoptions.phoneinput, function() {
                var number = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
                $(this).val(number)
            });
        }
    });
    
    return $.phonevalidation.js;
});
```

```js
// app/code/Sanne/Js/view/frontend/web/requirejs-config.js

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            phonevalidationjs:      'Sanne_Js/js/phonevalidation'
        }
    }
};
```

```xml
<!-- app/code/Sanne/Js/view/frontend/layout/customer_address_form.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="phonejs" template="Sanne_Js::js.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: This does prevent the telephone field from having letters but I need the input type to change so that if people enter their telephone number on mobile they get the number keyboard. I actually just found a solution and will post it under this question now.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Comment: @Sanne please share the solution, I shall be thankful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @Sanne proposed, I've implemented a Plugin (instead of overriding the whole thing)...

In my case, just wanted to convert the `type="text"` to `tel` on the telephone field (billing).

So..

```xml
<!-- /app/code/vendor/module/etc/frontend/di.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="layoutprocessor_streetlines"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

```php
// /app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

public function afterProcess(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject, $result, $jsLayout)
    {

    $result["components"]["checkout"]["children"]["steps"]["children"]["billing-step"]["children"]["payment"]
        ["children"]["afterMethods"]["children"]["billing-address-form"]["children"]["form-fields"]["children"]
        ["telephone"]['config']['elementTmpl'] = 'Vendor_Module/form/element/telephone';

        return $result;

}
```

```html
<!-- src/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/base/web/template/form/element/telephone.html -->

<input class="input-text" type="tel" data-bind="
    value: value,
    valueUpdate: 'keyup',
    hasFocus: focused,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        'aria-describedby': getDescriptionId(),
        'aria-required': required,
        'aria-invalid': error() ? true : 'false',
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled
    }" />
```